# ¿Cómo comparar las fechas dentro de un array?

Tags: c#

Quiero comparar las fechas y cuando encuentre la fecha que sea mayor  enviarle una imagen especial, esto es lo que llevo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;

namespace MOZO.WS
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Descripción breve de WsEstadoReferencia
    /// </summary>
    public class WsEstadoReferencia : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnVer"].ConnectionString);

            try
            {
                if (context.Request["ref"] != null)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Estado_Referencia01", cn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    SqlDataReader lector;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@referencia", context.Request["ref"]);

                    cn.Open();
                    lector = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    String[] fechas = new String[8];
                    while (lector.Read())
                    {
                        fechas[0] = lector["creacion"].ToString();
                        fechas[1] = lector["revalidacion"].ToString();
                        fechas[2] = lector["previo"].ToString();
                        fechas[3] = lector["fe.entrada"].ToString();
                        fechas[4] = lector["fe.pago"].ToString();
                        fechas[5] = lector["despacho"].ToString();
                        fechas[6] = lector["cta.gtos"].ToString();
                        fechas[7] = lector["liquidacion"].ToString();
                    }

                    Image bm = new Bitmap(900, 50);
                    Image[] a0 = new Bitmap[8];
                    Graphics objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
                    int padding = 82;

                    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                    {    
                        if (fechas[i] == "")
                            a0[i] = new Bitmap(context.Server.MapPath("~") + "images\\imagenesEdoReferencia\\g" + i + ".png");
                        else
                            a0[i] = new Bitmap(context.Server.MapPath("~") + "images\\imagenesEdoReferencia\\c" + i + ".png");

                        objGraphics.DrawImage(a0[i], new Point(padding * i, 0));
                    }

                    string ruta = Path.GetTempPath() + context.Request["ref"] + ".png";
                    bm.Save(ruta);

                    context.Response.Clear();
                    context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
                    context.Response.WriteFile(ruta);
                    //context.Response.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
            finally
            {
                cn.Close();
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero deberías tratar las fechas como tal, no como texto.
Puedes empezar por crear una función que convierta el resultado de tu consulta a un objeto `DateTime` y una que sirva para hacer la comparación:

```
private static DateTime GetDbDateTime(object DbResult)
{
    return DBNull.Value.Equals(DbResult) ? new DateTime() : (DateTime)DbResult;
}

private static DateTime MaxDateTime(DateTime[] fechas)
{
    // Para que esto funcione debes incluir una referencia al principio del archivo: using System.Linq;
    var _fechas = fechas.ToList<DateTime>();
    return _fechas.Max();
}
```

y utilizarla en tu procesamiento:

```
DateTime[] fechas = new DateTime[8];
while (lector.Read())
{
    fechas[0] = GetDbDateTime(lector["creacion"]);
    fechas[1] = GetDbDateTime(lector["revalidacion"]);
    fechas[2] = GetDbDateTime(lector["previo"]);
    fechas[3] = GetDbDateTime(lector["fe.entrada"]);
    fechas[4] = GetDbDateTime(lector["fe.pago"]);
    fechas[5] = GetDbDateTime(lector["despacho"]);
    fechas[6] = GetDbDateTime(lector["cta.gtos"]);
    fechas[7] = GetDbDateTime(lector["liquidacion"]);
}
```

Y a partir de ahí puedes hacer tu comparación:

```
DateTime maxDate = MaxDateTime(fechas);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{    
    if(fechas[i].Compare(maxDate) == 0)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus comentarios!  lo tomare en cuenta la proxima vez

Comment: @emanuelle Si te sirvió la respuesta, no olvides marcarla como solución (con la paloma debajo del número a la izquierda) para agradecer al autor y para que cualquiera que tenga el mismo o similar problema encuentre la solución!